# Animate SVG path to smaller size ( like a dot ) in number of seconds

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animate

Am trying to animate the following **SVG** from the current size to smaller size like a dot in number of seconds.

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
       <style type="text/css">
        .st3{fill:#E8D99C;stroke:#0C3854;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
       </style>
       <path 
           class="st3" 
           d="M220.8,724.8l-12.6,13.1c-2,2-5.1,2-7.1,0l-12.6-13.1c-2-2-2-5.4,0-7.4l12.6-13.1c2-2,5.1-2,7.1,0l12.6,13.1
     C222.8,719.4,222.8,722.8,220.8,724.8z"
       />
    </svg>
```

How can I achieve that with JavaScript or CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS transitions for this: `transition:transform, .5s`.  The main idea is to transform the shape around it's own center: `transform-origin: center center; transform-box: fill-box;`

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.st3{transform: scale(1, 1);
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:transform, .5s}
svg:hover path{ transform: scale(.1, .1);}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="186 702 37 38" width="300">
   <style type="text/css">
       .st3{fill:#E8D99C;stroke:#0C3854;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
   </style>
   <path
       class="st3" 
       d="M220.8,724.8l-12.6,13.1c-2,2-5.1,2-7.1,0l-12.6-13.1c-2-2-2-5.4,0-7.4l12.6-13.1c2-2,5.1-2,7.1,0l12.6,13.1
    C222.8,719.4,222.8,722.8,220.8,724.8z"
   />
</svg>
```

As an observation: your svg element doesn't have a `viewBox` attribute making the shape fall outside the svg canvas. I've added a viewBox and a width attribute to be able to see the shape.